# Access IVars Directly for Non-objects From Another Class?

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C 2.0, I usually make an `assign` property for ivars that are primitive types like `float`. Then it occurred to me that I can access them from outside the class with `obj->variable` notation. I imagine that this is bad practice: is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's bad practice because it breaks encapsulation of your class' implementation details. The `@property` declaration is a public API statement ("my class provides a *property* of type, e.g. `float`), not an implementation statement ("my class has a `float` instance variable"). Clients of your class' API should not know its implementation details lest you be prevented from changing those details without breaking client code.